# Graphing a pair of data vectors with a For Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, plot

I'm given a problem set with data for all the x coordinates in one vector and all the y coordinates in a second vector and I'm able to plot them fine with a single call function. But now I'm asked to run the same code, but now, plot it using a For Loop. I've never done for loops over 2 vectors before, so I'm a bit lost here.

Here's the exact breakdown of the question:

> Write a `for` loop that iterates over the two vectors, taking corresponding values of the `problem.8.x.data` vector and the `problem.8.y.data` and plotting a single point at that location:
>   * Then graph the sequence of points by iterating over the two vectors. (Hint: you can do this by iterating with an index, and then using positive integer indexing to select the elements from the two vectors.)- In the first iteration of the `for` loop, plot a point at the location where the $x$-coordinate is the first value of the `problem.8.x.data` vector and the $y$-coordinate is the first value of the `` problem.8.y.data` vector. - In the second iteration of the `for` loop, plot a point at the location where the $x$-coordinate is the second value of the `problem.8.x.data` vector and the $y$-coordinate is the second value of the ``problem.8.y.data`vector. - In the third iteration of the`for`loop, plot a point at the location where the $x$-coordinate is the third value of the`problem.8.x.data``` vector and the $y$-coordinate is the third value of the ``problem.8.y.data ``` vector. Your `for` loop should iterate over all the points, so make sure you get the upper limit right. (Hint: the $x$ and $y$ data vectors must have the same number of values, so you can just calculate the length of one of them to find the number of points.)

The length of each vector is 36 values so they match up. Originally I thought I had to be using two separate loops but it looks like they are keen on it being iterated over one loop to plot the points. My current code runs fine and gets the correct answer, but I don't think it's utilizing the for loop in any regard:

```
plot(
     x = NULL,
     xlim = c(-3, 3),
     ylim = c(0, 4),
     main = "Smile.8",
     xlab = "",
     ylab = "",
     las = 1
    )
for (index.8b in 1:length(problem.8.x.data)) {
  points( problem.8.x.data, problem.8.y.data,
  pch = 19,
  cex = 2,
  col = "royalblue3"
  )
}
```

Any advice on how to go about solving this problem?

Comment: First off, I don't see the indexed value `index.8b` being utilized in your `for` block.  E.g. `for (i in 1:5){print(i^2)}` utilizes `i`.  If `problem.8.x.data` is a data vector, then the `for` statement should probably look like `for(index.8b in problem.8.x.data)` with `index.8b` in the body of the block iterating over all `problem.8.x.data`.

Comment: As written, you're plotting all points on each iteration of the loop. The question wants you to use indexing to plot a different point each on each iteration. Just add `[index.8b]` to the end of your x and y in `points` (e.g. `problem.8.x.data[index.8b]`).

Comment: Thanks, both! Steve, yeah that was what I was confused about, as I was getting the same plot but it didn't seem to have anything to do with the for loop indexing.